# Formgroup control: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have a form and `equiid` control, I want check the value of `equiid`

```ts
if (this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid'].value===undefined){
  console.log("undefined value");
} else {
  console.log("has value");
}
```

but when `equiid` is empty, in console recieve:

```ts
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

May be

```js
this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid'] === undefined
```

It leads to the results you mentioned.

This is just an idea of mine, please correct me if there is any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify like this.

```
if (this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid'] == null || this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid'].value == null){
    console.log("undefined value");
}else{
    console.log("has value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid'] does not exist in your object

If it doesn't matter whether equiid exists or not you can try this: `this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid']?.value === undefined`

The **?** will return undefined if equiid doesn't exist and will not throw any error

In case that's not what you want I recommend you do a console.log(this.formGroupContent.controls) to check if it exists

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!this.formGroupContent.controls['equiid'].value){
    console.log("undefined value");
}else{
    console.log("has value");
}
```

`undefined` value falls on `if`

`null` value falls on `if`